# Sending files over FTPS (secure) using WinSCP .NET assembly

Tags: c#, ftp, winscp, ftps, winscp-net

What is required to send out files to a server with WinSCP (.NET assembly) using FTPS (Secure)?

I've been looking at their documentation and am not really clear on certain aspects like `TlsHostCertificateFingerprint` or `TlsClientCertificatePath`.

I've been able to send out files via FTP and SFTP with no problem, but this whole thing just eludes me.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

If you have a code for FTP, all you need to add to connect to a well-behaved FTPS (FTP over TLS/SSL) server is to set the [`SessionOptions.FtpSecure`](https://winscp.net/eng/docs/library_sessionoptions#ftpsecure):

```
// Set up session options
SessionOptions sessionOptions = new SessionOptions
{
    Protocol = Protocol.Ftp,
    HostName = "ftp.example.com",
    UserName = "username",
    Password = "password",
    // Enable FTPS in explicit mode, aka FTPES
    FtpSecure = FtpSecure.Explicit,
};

using (Session session = new Session())
{
    // Connect
    session.Open(sessionOptions);

    // Your code
}
```

---

The `TlsHostCertificateFingerprint` is needed only, if your server certificate is not signed by a trusted authority.

The `TlsClientCertificatePath` is needed only, if your server requires authenticating with a client certificate.

---

Easiest is to [configure your session in WinSCP GUI](https://winscp.net/eng/docs/ui_login) and have it [generate a code template](https://winscp.net/eng/docs/ui_generateurl#code) for you. That's actually how I got the above code.

Comment: I never saw the code-template-generation before...rocket!