# Powershell script to download file from FTPS server

Tags: powershell, download, filezilla, ftps

I have seen mixed posts but nothing definitive and recent.  I am running Filezilla Server FTPS Explicit TLS.  I need a Powershell script that when run will securely connect to my server across the internet and download a specific file.  Does the below code looks good minus the TLS, and can someone help me finish it? I think all of the commands I would need would be from here https://winscp.net/eng/docs/library_sessionoptions#ftpsecure

```
    # Load WinSCP .NET assembly
Add-Type -Path "WinSCPnet.dll"

# Setup session options
$sessionOptions = New-Object WinSCP.SessionOptions -Property @{
    Protocol = [WinSCP.Protocol]::Ftp
    HostName = "ftp.example.com"
    UserName = "user"
    Password = "mypassword"
}

$session = New-Object WinSCP.Session

try
{
    # Connect
    $session.Open($sessionOptions)

    # Download files
    $session.GetFiles("/directory/to/download/*", "C:\target\directory\*").Check()
}
finally
{
    # Disconnect, clean up
    $session.Dispose()
}
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Sending files over FTPS (secure) using WinSCP .NET assembly](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43766939/sending-files-over-ftps-secure-using-winscp-net-assembly)