# VB.NET 2010 - FTPs TLS Explicit Mode

Tags: vb.net, ssl, ftp, ftps

Context: I am trying to make an application that will store (when desired) the application configuration file for the user on an FTPs server in TLS Explicit mode.

Server: FileZilla Server for Windows

I have not been able to figure out the Cryptography and Certification handling in VB yet.
Been working on it for a week now and scrapped everything to start fresh.

To start from the beginning, here is what I've got.
Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Thank you!

```
Private Sub Button1_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    Dim UPReq As System.Net.FtpWebRequest = DirectCast(System.Net.WebRequest.Create("ftp://127.0.0.1/app/Test_File.txt"), System.Net.FtpWebRequest)
    UPReq.Credentials = New System.Net.NetworkCredential("FTPusername", "FTPpassword")
    'UPReq.ClientCertificates
    UPReq.EnableSsl = True
    UPReq.Method = System.Net.WebRequestMethods.Ftp.UploadFile
    Dim file() As Byte = System.IO.File.ReadAllBytes("C:\Users\" + Environment.UserName + "\Desktop\Test_File.txt")
    Dim Upload As System.IO.Stream = UPReq.GetRequestStream()
    Upload.Write(file, 0, file.Length)
    Upload.Close()
    Upload.Dispose()
End Sub
```

Comment: Have you considered using a library that already does it, like [Martin Prikryl's WinSCP](https://www.nuget.org/packages/WinSCP)? FTP via the built in classes always felt like a painful fudge to me, because they're quite "isolated request/response" centric but FTP is sometimes more like a terminal session

Comment: I see what you're saying, and I do use WinSCP as my main FTP client. However, to be honest, I wouldn't know the first thing on how to implement WinSCP into my application.

Comment: I put a link in the comment to the [nuget](https://www.nuget.org/packages/WinSCP) package; you install that (right click project in solution explorer and choose Manage Nuget pacakages) then go to the "[Project Site](https://winscp.net/eng/docs/library)" link on the nuget page; from there you'll see [examples](https://winscp.net/eng/docs/library#vbnet) of how to use it

Comment: Thank you for this, it was a bit difficult to install inside VS 2010. However, I got it installed. Now I just need to find out how to use their example code while modifying it for FTP with TLS instead of SFTP with SSH. Any ideas?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43766939/sending-files-over-ftps-secure-using-winscp-net-assembly ? The author posts here

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For anyone reading this in the future, USE WinSCP!

Their guides are amazing!

This is for all the current/future programmers!
In Visual Studio, go to `Tools > Extension Manager...` then install `NuGet Package Manager`, Restart Visual Studio.

Download and install WinSCP, then download the WinSCP NuGet package from [HERE](https://www.nuget.org/packages/WinSCP).
In Visual Studio right click on your project in the `Solution Explorer` then click on `Manage NuGet Packages...` then click on `Settings` in the bottom left.
Add the source (folder where you downloaded the WinSCP NuGet Package) then click `OK`.

Next, you will see `WinSCP .NET assembly` show up, click on it and hit `Install`.
Then make sure to add `Imports WinSCP` to the top of your project code.

After that you can code the functions for Connecting, Uploading, and Downloading.
Use their examples provided [HERE](https://winscp.net/eng/docs/library_examples)

MASSIVE TIP: Use WinSCP to connect to your FTPS server, then click on the `Session` tab and click on `Generate session URL/code`.
Inside the new window that appears, select the `.NET assembly code` tab. Then make sure your programming language is selected in the `Language` drop down.
There it is! It will show you the session connection code for your FTPS server, just copy and paste that into Visual Studio.

From there, you will have to do the rest to modify their example code, and combine it with the session connection code that WinSCP gave you.

Happy Coding!