# VB.NET 2010 - WinSCP Package for FTPS

Tags: vb.net, ssl, sftp, winscp, ftps

I have just installed the WinSCP library inside my VB project so I can use FTPS to transfer application files to/from a server.
However, and I apologize for my lack of knowledge, but how do I get their example code working in a practical setting?

I need to modify their code to use FTP with TLS instead of FTP over SSH as seen in their example code below.

```
Imports WinSCP
 
Friend Class Example
    Public Shared Function Main() As Integer
        Try 
            ' Setup session options
            Dim sessionOptions As New SessionOptions
            With sessionOptions
                .Protocol = Protocol.Sftp
                .HostName = "example.com"
                .UserName = "user"
                .Password = "mypassword"
                .SshHostKeyFingerprint = "ssh-rsa 2048 xxxxxxxxxxx...="
            End With
 
            Using session As New Session
                ' Connect
                session.Open(sessionOptions)
 
                ' Download files
                Dim transferOptions As New TransferOptions
                transferOptions.TransferMode = TransferMode.Binary
 
                Dim transferResult As TransferOperationResult
                transferResult =
                    session.GetFiles("/home/user/*", "d:\download\", False, transferOptions)
 
                ' Throw on any error
                transferResult.Check()
 
                ' Print results
                For Each transfer In transferResult.Transfers
                    Console.WriteLine("Download of {0} succeeded", transfer.FileName)
                Next
            End Using
            Return 0
        Catch e As Exception
            Console.WriteLine("Error: {0}", e)
            Return 1
        End Try
    End Function
End Class
```

Comment: See also [Sending files over FTPS (secure) using WinSCP .NET assembly](https://stackoverflow.com/q/43766939/850848).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There seem to be no YouTube videos/forum posts on a good solution for this.
So here is my solution!

This is for all the current/future programmers!
In Visual Studio, go to `Tools > Extension Manager...` then install `NuGet Package Manager`, Restart Visual Studio.

Download and install WinSCP, then download the WinSCP NuGet package from [HERE](https://www.nuget.org/packages/WinSCP).
In Visual Studio right click on your project in the `Solution Explorer` then click on `Manage NuGet Packages...` then click on `Settings` in the bottom left.
Add the source (folder where you downloaded the WinSCP NuGet Package) then click `OK`.

Next, you will see `WinSCP .NET assembly` show up, click on it and hit `Install`.
Then make sure to add `Imports WinSCP` to the top of your project code.

After that you can code the functions for Connecting, Uploading, and Downloading.
Use their examples provided [HERE](https://winscp.net/eng/docs/library_examples)

MASSIVE TIP: Use WinSCP to connect to your FTPS server, then click on the `Session` tab and click on `Generate session URL/code`.
Inside the new window that appears, select the `.NET assembly code` tab. Then make sure your programming language is selected in the `Language` drop down.
There it is! It will show you the session connection code for your FTPS server, just copy and paste that into Visual Studio.

From there, you will have to do the rest to modify their example code, and combine it with the session connection code that WinSCP gave you.

Happy Coding!

Answer (score 2):

This should work:

```
Dim sessionOptions As New SessionOptions
With sessionOptions
    .Protocol = Protocol.Ftp
    .HostName = "example.com"
    .UserName = "user"
    .Password = "mypassword"
    .FtpSecure = FtpSecure.Explicit
End With
```